# Load only currently logged-in user data in cells. (Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I have an app with a SignUp/LogIn authentication created with Firebase. When the user is connected, he can add a cell and fill in two text fields. Then the cell data like the date, the two fields filled by the user and the email of the user who created the cell are saved with Firestore. I want that when a user logs in, only the cells that this user has created are displayed. How I can do it?

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2gXm.png)

Here is my FStore struct :

```
struct FStore {
    static let collectionName = "cells"
    static let firstText = "firstText"
    static let secondText = "secondText"
    static let senders = "sender"
    static let dateField = "date"
}
```

Here I save the cell informations :

```
        let firstBody = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let secondBody = alert.textFields![1] as UITextField
        
        if firstBody.text != "" && secondBody.text != "" {
        
            if let cellSender = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
                
                self.db.collection(Constants.FStore.collectionName).addDocument(data: [Constants.FStore.senders: cellSender, Constants.FStore.firstText: firstBody.text!, Constants.FStore.secondText: secondBody.text!, Constants.FStore.dateField: Date().timeIntervalSince1970]) { error in
                    if let e = error {
                        print("Issue saving data to Firestore \(e)")
                    } else {
                        
                        print("succesfully saved")
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

CELLS struct :

```
struct CELLS {

let sender: String
let firstText: String
let secondText: String
}
```

Load Cell function (CellArray = [CELLS]) :

```
  func loadCells() {
   CellArray = []
    db.collection(Constants.FStore.collectionName).order(by: Constants.FStore.dateField).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        
        self.CellArray = []
        
        if let e = error {
            print("issue retrieving data \(e)")
        }else {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                let data = doc.data()
                    if let sender = data[Constants.FStore.senders] as? String, let cellFirst = data[Constants.FStore.firstText] as? String, let cellSecond = data[Constants.FStore.secondText] as? String {
                        
                        let newCell = CELLS(sender: sender, firstText: cellFirst, secondText: cellSecond)
                        self.CellArray.append(newCell)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I want to return only the user cells here :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    // Return only the currently logged-in user cells
    return CellArray.count
    
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking [how to filter the data from Firestore by using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - are you asking how to query Firestore for the users data (per the above comment) or are you asking how to return specific data from your dataSource to be displayed in a section in a tableView? Also you don't need this `DispatchQueue.main.async {` in Firestore closures as UI calls are always done on the main thread and networking calls are on a backgroung thread. Oh  and best practice when coding is vars start with a lowercase char (cellArray, not CellArray) - caps are reserved for Structures, Classes and Enums.